# Three.js - Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I'm getting the `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` while using Three.js.
The error is being shown for the line where I'm creating a `THREE.PerspectiveCamera`. 
The script is

```
window.requestAnimFrame = (function(callback){
        return window.requestAnimationFrame ||
        window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
        function(callback){
            window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
        };
    })();

    function animate(lastTime, angularSpeed, three){
        // update
        var date = new Date();
        var time = date.getTime();
        lastTime = time;

        // render
        three.renderer.render(three.scene, three.camera);

        // request new frame
        requestAnimFrame(function(){
            animate(lastTime, angularSpeed, three);
        });
    }

    $(window).bind('load',function(){
        var angularSpeed = 0.2; // revolutions per second
        var lastTime = 0;
        $container = $("#container");
        var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        $container.append(renderer.domElement);

        // camera - Uncaught Type Error on the below line
        var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
        camera.position.y = -450;
        camera.position.z = 400;
        camera.rotation.x = 45 * (Math.PI / 180);

        // scene
        var scene = new THREE.Scene();

        var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
                            color: 0x0000ff,
                        });
        var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
        for(var i=0;i<100;i++){
            geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(i-100,i-100,i-100));
            geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(i+100,i+100,i+100));
            var line = new Three.Line(geometry,material);
            scene.add(line);
            geometry=new THREE.Geometry();
        }


        // create wrapper object that contains three.js objects
        var three = {
            renderer: renderer,
            camera: camera,
            scene: scene,
        };

        animate(lastTime, angularSpeed, three);
    });
```

Is this because the way I'm declaring the camera is wrong?
I checked the three.js documentation and the example give there is basically the same.
So I'm stuck on what to do.

UPDATE:
I was using a local copy of Three.js when I encountered the last error. I switched it with the link http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/libraries/Three.js. 
Now, the PerspectiveCamera error is gone, but it produces a new error inside the Three.js script. The error is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined` on line 337 of the Three.js script

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, can you try to type this `new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);` directly to the console and update your post with the output?

Comment: @LimH. It gives the same error, "UncaughtTypeError: undefined is not a function". Is it because the browser doesn't support perspective camera?

Comment: I've been trying the script in Chromium by enabling the "Override Software Rendering" option. I tried it in firefox and it shows --
"TypeError: THREE.PerspectiveCamera is not a constructor".

Comment: http://www.johannes-raida.de/tutorials/three.js/tutorial07/tutorial07.htm check out the conditional statements about if your supporting WebGl. where are you importing the three.js library from?

Comment: @Four_lo i was using a local copy that i had got from an example till now. I tried another link http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/libraries/Three.js which seems to solve the problem with the camera, but produces the same error inside the Three.js file, "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined "

Comment: I dont think you can just rotate the camera on the x axis, Change the camera.lookAt property while offsetting the camera.x position

Comment: @Four_lo I tried commenting the rotation x of camera, but still the error is produced

Comment: "cannot read property 'x' of undefined is still produced?, if thats true try putting in an x position value. three.js reads the coordinates X,Y, then Z. it might want an x value before moving on

Comment: @Four_lo I tried an example for sphere and it seems to work fine. So, the problem is where I'm creating and adding lines to the scene. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: at first glance I might suggest adding another vertices.push line for the third dimension. I am looking into it further though

Comment: @Four_lo I tried it with another copy of three.js, from mrdoob.github.com and now the lines are rendering. I'll have to check if it is rendering correctly, but the errors are gone.

Comment: you can take out the comma in after scene in your wrapper object, but that would just be horrible if that was the cause of all this so it cant be

Comment: @rahules ah good. I learned way too much about three.js for today

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The problem with the local copy is you used the unbuilt Three.js file (that would be src/Three.js). The one you want is either build/three.js or build/three.min.js. I copied that into my project, and changed the reference to it in the script tag's src attribute, and it all started working.

In short:

```
mrdoob-three.js-2524525(or some other number here)
 |
 +----build
 |     |
 |     +--three.js     <-- YES, CORRECT FILE
 |     +--three.min.js <-- YES
 |     ...
 |
 +----src
 ...   |
       +--Three.js     <-- NO, PREBUILT FILE THAT ONLY CONTAINS CONSTANTS
       ...
```