# three.js code working is JSfiddle but not in my browser

Tags: javascript, three.js, jsfiddle

Here is a simple three.js code that creates a custom geometry http://jsfiddle.net/67Lgzjpb/.
When I try to run this directly on my browser, (not throught JSFiddle) it says

```
TypeError: geom.computeCentroids is not a function
```

Has anyone got a clue why?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15471879/three-js-uncaught-typeerror-undefined-is-not-a-function ?

Comment: Nope that is not it.

Answer (score 2):

It is because the fiddle is linking to a version of three.js that is two years old.

Hopefully, you are linking to the current version.

The method `Geometry.computeCentroids()` no longer exists, and `Face3` no longer has a `centroid` property.

three.js r.68