# three.js beginner stuck on first step: "undefined is not a function"

Tags: javascript, three.js

My problem is the same as this question: [Three.js - Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15471879/) -- which did not have a solution that works for me.

I am starting on the Getting Started page in three.js (http://threejs.org/docs/index.html#Manual/Introduction/Creating_a_scene) which presents an
application with the three.js library in a folder accompanying the HTML file. The heart of the code is here:

```
<script src="js/three.js"></script>
<script>
  // Javascript will go here
  var scene = new THREE.Scene();
  var camera = THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, 
              window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000 );
  var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

  var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
  var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0x00ff00} );
  var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
  scene.add( cube );

  camera.position.z = 1000;

  function render() { 
    requestAnimationFrame( render ); 
    renderer.render( scene, camera ); 
  } 
  render();
</script>
```

One may use either the minimized library (`three.min.js`) in which case I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` and Chrome developer tools cites a line in that file. Likewise, using the unminimized version (`three.js`) from the `mr.doob` build folder, the same error occurs but on line 10614. In three.js this is the blank line above `this.updateProjectionMatrix()` in the following code:

```
THREE.PerspectiveCamera = function ( fov, aspect, near, far ) {

    THREE.Camera.call( this );

    this.type = 'PerspectiveCamera';


    this.zoom = 1;

    this.fov = fov !== undefined ? fov : 50;
    this.aspect = aspect !== undefined ? aspect : 1;
    this.near = near !== undefined ? near : 0.1;
    this.far = far !== undefined ? far : 2000;

    this.updateProjectionMatrix();

};
```

Notice the use of `undefined` in the four lines above where the error pointed.

I am presenting the code using a MAMP Web server. I have installed it both on my iMac and my Windows 8 PC. The page has failed to appear in both Chrome and Firefox always with the same diagnostic message.

I feel I'm making some very basic error. Help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You missed the tiny word "new" when creating an instance of THREE.PerspectiveCamera:

```
<script src="js/three.js"></script>
<script>
  // Javascript will go here
  var scene = new THREE.Scene();
  var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, 
              window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000 );
  var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

  var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
  var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0x00ff00} );
  var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
  scene.add( cube );

  camera.position.z = 1000;

  function render() { 
    requestAnimationFrame( render ); 
    renderer.render( scene, camera ); 
  } 
  render();
</script>
```

Also please note, that you won't see much as your camera is too far away from that tiny box :)

Make it

```
camera.position.z = 50;
```

to see your box shining in green in front of you..